# geth’s "debug_traceTransaction" vs parity's "trace_replayTransaction"

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, transaction-trace

Is it at all possible to transform geth’s `debug_traceTransaction` trace into something that looks like what you get from parity's `trace_replayTransaction`? Parity’s trace module is *extraordinarily* useful for seeing the exact sequence of calls that led to a transaction reverting ([eg](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x312d79e876584c6cb72067ed0795339ea9ebe9b3d42c41c8ced7a8a3f0433659&type=parity)), and for getting storage slot diffs. But, Geth is preferable to use in certain situations so I was curious to know if I'm vender locked to parity if I want that nice call trace?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a clean-ish call trace from `debug_traceTransaction`.

What you do is loop through the Geth trace frames:

If you find an `op` that is `CALL`, `DELEGATECALL`, or `STATICCALL`, you can extract the contract address from the `frame["stack"][-2][-20:]`.
The `CALLDATA` is found in the `frame["memory"]` for each of these opcodes. However, to locate it varies for each:

- If you are in a `CALL`, the offset is `frame["stack"][-4]` and the size is `frame["stack"][-5]`. Also, the value given to the `CALL` is found at frame["stack"][-3]`.
- If you are in a `DELEGATECALL`, the offset for calldata is found at `frame["stack"][-3]` and the size is `frame["stack"][-4]`.
- If you are in a `STATICCALL`, the offset for calldata is found at `frame["stack"][-3]` and the size is `frame["stack"][-4]`.

After that, you can find the next `RETURN` opcode after the call and extract the `returndata` by grabbing the offset from `frame["stack"][-1]` and the size from `frame["stack"][-2]` and using that to extract the values from `frame["memory"]`.

I know the storage is available on Geth style traces but am not familiar on how to make those conversion into a Parity-style format, regarding the diff.

One other problem that you may encounter is gas calculations. There is not a clear and easy way to get the same gas values between Geth and Parity, as far as I know. Calculating gas requires knowing the last step in an internal `CALL` and there isn't a clear way to figure that out, as far as I know.